# Dispose (cancel) observable. SubscribeOn and observeOn different schedulers

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

**Reformed question**

I have reformed my question. To the common case.

I want to generate items with RxSwift in background thread (loading from disk, long-running calculations, etc.), and observe items in MainThread. And I want to be sure that no items will be delivered after dispose (from main thread).

According to documentation (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#disposing):

> So can this code print something after the dispose call is executed? The answer is: it depends.
>
> - If the scheduler is a serial scheduler (ex. MainScheduler) and dispose is called on the same serial scheduler, the answer is no.
> - Otherwise it is yes.

But in case of using subscribeOn and observerOn with different schedulers - we cannot guarantee that nothing will be emitted after dispose (manual or by dispose bag, it does not matter).

How should I generate items (images, for example) in background and be sure that result will not be used after the dispose?

I made workaround in real project, but I want to solve this problem and to understand how should we avoid it in the same cases.

In my test project I have used small periods - they demonstrate the problem perfectly!

```
import RxSwift

class TestClass {
    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    private var isCancelled = false

    init(cancelAfter: TimeInterval, longRunningTaskDuration: TimeInterval) {
        assert(Thread.isMainThread)

        load(longRunningTaskDuration: longRunningTaskDuration)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + cancelAfter) { [weak self] in
            self?.cancel()
        }
    }

    private func load(longRunningTaskDuration: TimeInterval) {
        assert(Thread.isMainThread)

        // We set task not cancelled
        isCancelled = false

        DataService
            .shared
            .longRunngingTaskEmulation(sleepFor: longRunningTaskDuration)
            // We want long running task to be executed in background thread
            .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(queue: .global()))
            // We want to process result in Main thread
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] (result) in
                assert(Thread.isMainThread)

                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }

                if !strongSelf.isCancelled {
                    print("Should not be called! Task is cancelled!")
                } else {
                    // Do something with result, set image to UIImageView, for instance
                    // But if task was cancelled, this method will set invalid (old) data
                    print(result)
                }

                }, onError: nil)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    // Cancel all tasks. Can be called in PreapreForReuse.
    private func cancel() {
        assert(Thread.isMainThread)

        // For test purposes. After cancel, old task should not make any changes.
        isCancelled = true

        // Cancel all tasks by creating new DisposeBag (and disposing old)
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
}

class DataService {
    static let shared = DataService()

    private init() { }

    func longRunngingTaskEmulation(sleepFor: TimeInterval) -> Single<String> {
        return Single
            .deferred {
                assert(!Thread.isMainThread)

                // Enulate long running task
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: sleepFor)

                // Return dummy result for test purposes.
                return .just("Success")
        }
    }
}

class MainClass {
    static let shared = MainClass()

    private init() { }

    func main() {

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.150, repeats: true) { [weak self] (_) in
            assert(Thread.isMainThread)

            let longRunningTaskDuration: TimeInterval = 0.050

            let offset = TimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(20)) / 1000.0
            let cancelAfter = 0.040 + offset

            self?.executeTest(cancelAfter: cancelAfter, longRunningTaskDuration: longRunningTaskDuration)
        }
    }

    var items: [TestClass] = []
    func executeTest(cancelAfter: TimeInterval, longRunningTaskDuration: TimeInterval) {
        let item = TestClass(cancelAfter: cancelAfter, longRunningTaskDuration: longRunningTaskDuration)
        items.append(item)
    }
}
```

Call MainClass.shared.main() somewhere to start.

We call method to load some data and later we call cancel (all from Main Thread). After cancel we sometimes receive the result (in main thread too), but it is old already.

In real project TestClass is a UITableViewCell subclass and cancel method is called in prepareForReuse. Then cell is being reused and new data is set to the cell. And later we get the result of OLD task. And old image is set to the cell!

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION (OLD):**

I would like to load image with RxSwift in iOS. I want to load image in background, and to use it in main thread. So I subscribeOn background thread, and observeOn main thread. And function will look like this:

```
func getImage(path: String) -> Single<UIImage> {
    return Single
        .deferred {
            if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
                return Single.just(image)
            } else {
                return Single.error(SimpleError())
            }
        }
        .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
}
```

But I get problems with cancelation. Because different schedulers are used to create items and to call dispose (disposing from main thread), subscription event can be raised after dispose is called. So in my case of using in UITableViewCell I receive invalid (old) image.

If I create item (load image) in the same scheduler that observes (Main thread), everything works fine!
But I would like to load images in background and I want it will be canceled after disposing (in prepareForReuse method or in new path set method). What is the common template for this?

**EDIT:**

I have created a test project, where I can emulate the problem when the event is received after dispose.

And I have one simple solution that works. We should emit items in the same scheduler. So we should capture scheduler and emit items there (after long running task completes).

```
func getImage2(path: String) -> Single<UIImage> {
    return Single
        .create(subscribe: { (single) -> Disposable in
            // We captrure current queue to execute callback in
            // TODO: It can be nil if called from background thread
            let callbackQueue = OperationQueue.current

            // For async calculations
            OperationQueue().addOperation {
                // Perform any long-running task
                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)

                // Emit item in captured queue
                callbackQueue?.addOperation {
                    if let result = image {
                        single(.success(result))
                    } else {
                        single(.error(SimpleError()))
                    }
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create()
        })
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
}
```

But it is not in Rx way. And I think this is not the best solution.

May be I should use CurrentThreadScheduler to emit items, but I cannot understand how. Is there any tutorial or example of items generation with schedulers usage? I did not find any.

Comment: I suspect your problem is elsewhere. Once you unsubscribe to an observable (by calling dispose on its disposable) there's no way you could possibly get a .next event with the image even if the background thread *did* finish loading it.

Comment: The problem is occured if the dispose is called _instantly_ after emitting element. Looks like item is queued to main queue and when we call dispose (in main thread) new item is in queue already. So it is received after dispose is called.

Comment: What is your use case for calling `dispose` manually?

Comment: I use DisposeBag in Subclass of UITableViewCell. I create new DisposeBag in prepareForReuse method and in the set(_:) method of the cell. I have tried the DisposeBag and manual dispose, result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting test case. There is a small bug, it should be `if strongSelf.isCancelled` instead of `if !strongSelf.isCancelled`. Apart from that, the test case shows the problem.

I would intuitively expect that it is checked whether a dispose has already taken place before emitting, if it happens on the same thread.

I found additionally this:

> just to make this clear, if you call dispose on one thread (like
>   main), you won't observe any elements on that same thread. That is a
>   guarantee.

see here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/38

So maybe it is a bug.

To be sure I opened an issue here:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1778

**Update**

It seems it was actually a bug. Meanwhile, the fine people at RxSwift have confirmed it and fortunately fixed it very quickly. See the issue link above.

**Testing**

The bug was fixed with commit `bac86346087c7e267dd5a620eed90a7849fd54ff`. So if you are using CocoaPods, you can simply use something like the following for testing:

```
target 'RxSelfContained' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RxAtomic', :git => 'https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git', :commit => 'bac86346087c7e267dd5a620eed90a7849fd54ff'
  pod 'RxSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git', :commit => 'bac86346087c7e267dd5a620eed90a7849fd54ff'
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work with my problem.
I have tested with the latest version of RxSwift (4.4.0) and it works fine!